# C# How to change status code 302 to 301?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have the following list of 302's, with the protocol as "http":

- "mydomain.com"
- "mydomain.com/about"
- "mydomain.com/services"
- "www.mydomain.com"
- "www.mydomain.com/about"
- "www.mydomain.com/portfolio"

And they all need to be 301 permanent with protocol "https":

- "www.mydomain.com{anything}"

The website automatically redirects from "http" to "https".  How do I change these 302's to 301 in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Where are you redirecting http to https?

Comment: You can do all this from the Web.Config, and you can use IIS to setup the Web.config for you